# How to check for string inequality in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

How is this possible?

```
select count(*) from happiness where source = 'love';
-[ RECORD 1 ]
count | 0

select count(*) from happiness where source != 'love';
-[ RECORD 1 ]
count | 9279

select count(*) from happiness;
-[ RECORD 1 ]---
count | 1418962...
```

And the \d

```
 source                           | character varying(255)      |
```

I'm going to punch myself in the face really hard when I get the answer to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL uses a so-called "three-valued" logic, whereby a given boolean expression can be either "true", "false", or "null". A query of this form:

```
select count(*) from happiness where ...;
```

will only return records where `...` is "true", skipping the records where it's either "false" or "null".

When `source` is null, `source = 'love'` and `source != 'love'` are both null; so both versions of your queries will skip any records where `source` is null. (`NOT (source = 'love')` will also be null: `not` "true" is "false", and `not` "false" is "true", but `not` null is still null.)

The reason for this behavior is that `null` represents "unknown"; if `source` is null, then there's no way to know whether it's "really" supposed to be `'love'`, or "really" supposed to be something else. (I think we tend to think of null as a distinct value, different from all others, but that's not its intended meaning.)

What you probably want is:

```
select count(*) from happiness where source is null or source != 'love';
```

Comment: That did it. My face hurts

Comment: Mine too, after spending too much time on this (and thinking I knew PG and SQL reasonabley well!).

Comment: Another option for this solution would be, I believe: `select count(*) from happiness where coalesce(source, '') != 'love';`

Comment: @cjauvin: Yes, indeed; that doesn't work in all DBMSes, but if you know your query will only be used in ones where it *does* work (such as PostgreSQL, as the OP is using), then -- great. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do it:

```
select count(*) from happiness where source is null;
```

if **source is null** then **source is not equal to love** but also **source is not different to love**